# Conjugacy classes in extra special $p$-groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

By definition, an extra-special $p$-group $G$ is a non-abelian $p$-group such that $Z=Z(G)$ is cyclic of order $p$ and $\frac{G}{Z}$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group. I read somewhere that obviously the conjugacy class sizes of such a group is $\{1,p\}$ and I was trying to prove this fact.
To prove this, I'd pick an element $x \in G$ and I assume it's a non-central element; otherwise its class size equals 1. Since $\frac{G}{Z}$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group, it follows that $x^p \in Z$, and we know $Z$ is cyclic of size $p$, therefore $x^{p^2}=1$. So the order of $x$ is either $p$ or $p^2$. 
I am not sure where to go from here. Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: The conjugacy class of $x$ is contained in the coset $xG'$ (can you see why?).  What do you know about $G'$?

Comment: Interesting! Thanks! Yes I can convince myself that the conjugacy class of $x$ is contained in the coset  $xG'$. I believe if I pick a commutator element, say $[s,t]$, and raise it to the p-th power, I get $[s^p,t]=1$. But apparently there's more and $G' = Z$, right?

Comment: Note that $g^{-1}xg = x[x,g]$. Also, since you only care about the size of the conjugacy class, ask yourself how big the set $xG'$ is.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, so I believe $|xG'|=|G'|=p$, and hence the conjugacy class size of x, has at most $p$ elements, and since class sizes are divisors of $G$, which is a $p$-group, the conjugacy class size is either 1 or $p$.

Comment: Perfect!${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks so much for walking me through it Steve!. I just learned a neat trick from you! :)